# Sorting a list of strings by the number within each string

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort the list provided below, yes it's full of strange values, but it's the data I have to work with.

The expected result is:

```
["3 $", "4 $", "4a $", "5-5b $$", "6 $", "10 $", "10 b $", "11 $"]
```

But instead I get:

```
["10 $", "10 b $", "11 $", "3 $", "4 $", "4a $", "5-5b $$", "6 $"]
```

This happens because `"10" < "3"` is `true`.

But I'm at a loss as to how I would go about comparing these values without converting them to numbers, in which case another issue will arise, namely the sorting of values such as  `"4 $", "4a $",  "4b $", "4c $"`.

```
let list = ["5-5b $$", "4 $", "10 $", "10 b $", "4a $", "6 $", "3 $", "11 $"];
```

Here is my code so far:

```
console.log(list.sort(function(a, b) {
 let x = a.replace(/\-/, ".").replace(/\$+/, "").replace(/\s/g, "");
 let y = b.replace(/\-/, ".").replace(/\$+/, "").replace(/\s/g, "");
 
 console.log(`Comparing ${x} to ${y}`)
 
 return x.localeCompare(y);
}))
```

All input is appreciated.

Comment: First you need to decide how you would order them. Are you trying to sort by the first number in the string? How do you handle `5-5b`? Does `4 a` come before `4b` (aka do spaces matter) etc etc.

Comment: just take the second answer with `localeCompare` and options.

Comment: I think splitting the elements of the list (on the basis of whitespace as well as "-"), and then sorting on the basis of first element might do the trick.